# Why invliad opcode always 0000

Tags: kernel, panic

Every time seeing an invalid opcode, it always shows 0000, what does this 0000 mean?

ex:

```
kernel BUG at arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c:1364!
invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
```

0000 means opcode is 0000, or execution result is 0000, or error code is 0000, or something else?

btw, I can't find the kernel code where it prints this line, only:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/bug.c#L204

```
    if (file)
        pr_crit("kernel BUG at %s:%u!\n", file, line);
```

not sure this place is the right place to print it.

Comment: what is going on at `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c:1364` for the source code in question

Comment: please ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715698/why-mce-panic-4-18-kernel-pass-5-15-kernel